# Postgres Osm2pgsql Error: role does not exist

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap

I've been setting up osm2pgsql to convert .osm files to be usable in Postgres.
I have now tried the following statement:

osm2pgsql --merc -d sa sa.osm

I am given the following error:
"Connection to database failed: FATAL: role "myUsername" does not exist

I have read up about this kind of error which is usually run into when using Postgres. I have created a new role in Postgres but still the error persists.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You didn't specify `-U|--username` switch, so `osm2pgsql` gets current username from terminal (unless you set `PGUSER` environment variable). Error message looks very clear, telling that role named `myUsername` does not exist in your database cluser. Note that:

```
CREATE ROLE myUsername LOGIN;    -- creating role myusername
CREATE ROLE "myUsername" LOGIN;  -- creating role myUsername
```

will produce two **different** roles:

```
SELECT rolname FROM pg_roles;
  rolname   
------------
 postgres
 myUsername
 myusername
(3 rows)
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but things have changed in OSM and this answer appears to be at the top of a Google search

Use this:

```
/usr/bin/install-postgis-osm-user.sh the-database-here your-username-here
```

for example

```
/usr/bin/install-postgis-osm-user.sh gis barrythefish
```